# Crash error: [__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (10) beyond bounds (10)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know this seems to be a fairly common error, but I'm going crazy trying to sort out why I'm getting this message. As I scroll down my tableView, the console throws me this:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (10) beyond bounds (10)'*

Any idea how I can fix this? I'm trying to get the number of items in the array storageData (e.g. return [storageData count];) See code below.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.storageData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    userName.text = [[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] objectForKey:@"name"];
    emailAddress.text = [[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] objectForKey:@"mail"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user]);

      NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
      [viewParams setValue:@"storeditems" forKey:@"view_name"];
      [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        self.descripData = responseObject;
          NSLog(@"%@",self.descripData);

     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }];

    [DIOSNode nodeIndexWithPage:@"0" fields:@"title" parameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"storage_item", nil] pageSize:@"20" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

       __block int iCount = 0;

        for (id object in responseObject) {
        //    NSLog(@"adding object!");
            [self.storageData setObject:(NSDictionary *)object forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",iCount]];
            iCount++;

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //failure
    }];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [storageData count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"StorageItemTableViewCell";

    StorageItemTableViewCell *cell = (StorageItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)

        {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StorageItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

            NSDictionary *tmp = [self.storageData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(long)indexPath.row]];

        [[cell itemName] setText:(NSString *)[tmp objectForKey:@"title"]];

              NSString *title = [tmp objectForKey:@"title"];
              [[cell itemName] setText:title];


            NSDictionary *node = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell itemDescrip] setText:[node objectForKey:@"body"]];


            NSString *secondLink = [[self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo"];

            [cell.itemPhoto sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];

              }

              return cell;
              }
```

Comment: What's the contents of self.descripData? It looks like you have a discrepancy between the storageData element count and the items in descripData.

Comment: @BradBrighton I had a feeling that might be the case... descripData is data being pulled from one field, and storageData contains data from another. That said, all nodes (pages) contain the same amount of data, so I didn't think that would be an issue? E.g. Every page contains data in both fields?

Comment: Sounds like you're making assumptions. Don't assume; use the debugger or NSLog() to inspect and see what, if anything, is different. There's no guarantee I'm right, but objectAtIndex: is sent to your descripData, and indexPath.row is based on numberOfRowsInSection pulled out of storageData.

Comment: *Any idea how I can fix this?* Don't index beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Point out the exact line of code casing the crash.

Comment: @BradBrighton When I do "return [descripData count];" I don't get a crash :) I assume this is because descripData exceeds the number of values in storageData?

Comment: The other way around; the number of items in storageData determines the number of rows your tableView will _attempt_ to display. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath you're using the row (10, in the specific case) as an index into descripData, and 10 is out of bounds, so you have at most 9 items in descripData. Again, there's no reason to guess at this. Inspect the data. If you don't, you may make the problem disappear for now, but it will likely bite you again when the data changes, or worse, you'll have an invisible bug where there's no crash but not all your data appears.

Comment: @BradBrighton Oooooh I get it (apologies for my newb tendencies). So because descripData only has 9 items and storageData has more, it's attempting to access "10", as storageData dictates how many rows are going to be displayed. Sorry for the lengthy discussion, just trying to educate myself :)

Comment: No worries, we were all new at this at some point. I think you're on the correct path to understanding the crash itself, yes. Now, you previously stated that you thought the data was the same. Your homework is to understand why (a) the data is different or (b) your understanding was incomplete (or, I suppose, (c), both).

Comment: FYI: @BradBrighton Did your homework, ran through the data, fixed the issue :) Thank you!! -B